# Exporting Google Notebook pages to xml file with utf8 encoding

Tags: utf-8, export, atom-feed, google-notebook

Google announced that [Notebook will be closed](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/fall-spring-clean.html) soon and the current notebooks will be moved to Google Docs. Instead of using Google Docs, I want to download the content as an xml (atom) file and use some other online service such as one of [these](http://project89.com/google-notebook-closed-alternatives-169/).

When I export the data, I see a question mark on non-Latin characters such as Turkish letters 'şŞğĞıİ'. Is there a way to download the content with utf8 support?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Just for the record, from the list you showed, none were to my liking. Too big. I wanted something as simple as Google Notebook itself. So I started the development of [jottinx](http://jottinx.com) as a free alternative for Google Notebook. Maybe check it out? I apologise for the shameless promotion, but I want feedback from users. The software is currently still in development/beta.

Comment: @nathanvda I've exported my notebooks correctly and imported them to jottinx and the characters are perfectly transferred. Thank you very much for the suggestion, it looks very promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same problem with Google Chrome, but I was able to download the xml files in UTF-8 encoding using IE9.

I don't know whether this has something to do with the browser selection, though; I haven't tried on Firefox yet.

Comment: Yes, it works fine when I export them with IE9 when the Google Notebook interface is in Turkish, such that it is 'Google Not Deftefi'. The atom feed has still question marks when I do it with Chrome even the Google Notebook interface is in Turkish.

Answer (score 0):

I want to know the answer too.
However as an emergency alternative, ZOHO's notebook importer could correctly handle the encoding.